# Copying Features/Backlog Items & tasks in Visual Studio Team Services into another project

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops, scrum

We have created a template for projects in Visual Studio Team Services (previously Visual Studio Online) and want to be able to copy all the features with the backlog items and tasks into a new project.

See image - https://i.stack.imgur.com/9LWU7.jpg

Is there anyway that this can be done as the only option I can see it to move it to another project but I still want to keep it in the Template project and copy it into another.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Excel to export these work items and then import into the new project. Refer to this link for details: [Bulk add or modify work items with Excel](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel).

You can also "Create copy of work item" from Query and then select which project to copy from the dialog pop up.
[image]

Comment: Thanks - You absolute hero! I never knew about the team tab on excel :) Pretty handy!

Comment: It is preferred if answers are self contained. Does this answer need more detail added in case of the link becoming broken?

Comment: This copy functionality of back log items works for single elements. How does this work for a collection of back log items, with different layers of Features, User Stories, Task and Tests?  Thx